# Stop animation on hover

Tags: html, css, transformation

I would like to apply my transformation (rotation) active until the hover state is out.
Unfortunately, after the rotation, my image retrieve his original rotation (to 0deg) immediately even the mouse is still over my picture.

I saw a lot of similar issues and answers but none of them are solving my problem.

Excuse me for my English and have a nice day!
Best regards.
Nicolas.

```css
#centerDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.rotation{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    animation-play-state:paused;
}
.rotation:hover{
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction:normal;
    animation-play-state:running;
}
@keyframes rotation{
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: rotate(-10deg); 
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="centerDiv">
  <img class="rotation" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/aaaaaa/fff" alt="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the animation to go back to a rotation of 0deg, then you don't really need animation, but `transition`.

```css
#centerDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.rotation{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 200ms;
}
.rotation:hover{
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    transition: transform 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="centerDiv">
  <img class="rotation" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/aaaaaa/fff" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm new to animations, so I'm trying a lot of things by using them.
I appreciate your help.
Sincerely. Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `animation-fill-mode` property in the `.rotation` class to `forwards`; if you tried setting it in the `:hover` state - it would've reset to the initial property value after the element is no longer hovered.

```css
#centerDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.rotation{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    animation-play-state:paused;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.rotation:hover{
    animation-name: rotation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction:normal;
    animation-play-state:running;
}
@keyframes rotation{
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: rotate(-10deg); 
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="centerDiv">
  <img class="rotation" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/aaaaaa/fff" alt="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question right but if you want your picture to keep rotating *as long* as the mouse is hovering on it, then you can set the

*animation-iteration-count: infinit;*

instead of setting it to 1.

This way the animation keeps going on a loop. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot but I don't want to loop!

Comment: This is good information. And, while the question itself is badly formed, I think the OP is looking for a way to stop animation on hover, rather than a way to keep it going.